# referring Env variables for Docker container in Fargete ECS cluster

Tags: spring-boot, docker, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager

In AWS Fargete cluster,we have spring boot application where we are using RDS aurora.
Here they are using AWS secret manager to store DB password.

In of the container definition we have provided

```
Environment:
    - Name: 'spring.datasource.url'
             Value: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:Secret-Maneger-Name:SecretString:DBURL}}
```

Secret-string has URL,username and password.And again in DBURL there is DB connection url.

I have below two queries

1. How should i use this environment variable in code to fetch username,endpoint and password ?.Any 
   sample code will be helpful.
2. Why again ":DBURL" added in value at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can consume these variable as same as other environment variables, the only difference between `value` and `valuefrom` is value get static value while value from value injects to the container during run time.

So your current syantax does not seems correct if you want to inject from the secret manager. it should be `valueFrom` where it will refer to `ARN` of the secret.

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:secret_name-AbCdEf"
    }]
  }]
}
```

**Environment variables**

> You may also designate AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store keys or
>   ARNs using the 'valueFrom' field. ECS will inject the value into
>   containers at run-time.

Required [IAM Permissions for Amazon ECS Secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html)
To use this feature, you must have the Amazon ECS task execution role and reference it in your task definition. This allows the container agent to pull the necessary AWS Systems Manager or Secrets Manager resources.

**Important!**

For tasks that use the **EC2 launch type, you must use the ECS agent configuration variable** `ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE=true` to use this feature. You can add it to the `./etc/ecs/ecs.confi`g file during container instance creation or you can add it to an existing instance and then restart the ECS agent. For more information, [see Amazon ECS Container Agent Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html).

[specifying-sensitive-data-task-definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html)

Comment: It does not look like the syntax is incorrect as we are also using another Environment variable  - Name: 'data.collect.apigee.transfer'
              Value: 'https://transfer-dev.XXX.com/dataXXXX/dataXXXX'  .And this is working fine.

Comment: which service you are using ec2 or fargate? and seems like you are using cloudformation? the syntax is based on task definition.

Comment: ECS Fargete we are using.And we are using Cloudformation.The Enviroment variables i showed above are defined in cloud-formation task definition